# Firebase function - sending img to storage bucket successful, but - "Error creating access token"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I may be having a brain fart, but I'm struggling to find the correct way to do this.

Task: I am providing an image URL to a cloud function and having it saved to a storage bucket. The function succeeds and the image is there in the Firebase control panel, but on clicking it I get an error,
"*Error creating access token*" and can't view the image.

My Bucket rules allow writing by Admin, though I tested "*allow write;*" also to no effect.

I'm working from the following example code. https://fergusfrl.com/blog/upload-an-image-to-firebase-storage-from-a-url

I have tried passing in `public: true` and `predefinedAcl: 'publicRead'` as suggested elsewhere on StackOverflow into the writeStream to no effect also.

Here's the example function below. Can anyone help with why this isn't working, or what I may need to pass in to create an access token? I would also like to get a download URL back, but the main focus is on this access token issue for now.

Thanks in advance.

```
exports.saveImageToStorage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const { imageUrl, destination } = req.body;
    axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: imageUrl,
        responseType: 'stream'
    }).then(async response => {
      const file = admin.storage().bucket().file(destination);
      const writeStream = file.createWriteStream({
          contentType: 'image/jpeg',
          public: true
      });
      await response.data.pipe(writeStream)
          .on('finish', () => {
              console.log('Successfully uploaded image');
              res.status(200).send();
          })
          .on('error', () => {
              console.log('Error uploading image');
              res.status(500).send();
          })
    }).catch(() => {
        console.log('Error fetching image');
        res.status(500).send();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make the file public in your code against the access rules of your storage bucket. So you need to turn the public access to false and generate an access token for the file while you upload it. I suggest [uuidv4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuidv4) for your `firebaseStorageDownloadTokens`. See sample code below:

```
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');

exports.saveImageToStorage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const { imageUrl, destination } = req.body;
    axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: imageUrl,
        responseType: 'stream'
    }).then(async response => {
      const file = admin.storage().bucket().file(destination);
      const uuid = uuidv4();
      const writeStream = file.createWriteStream({
          metadata: {
            contentType: 'image/png',
            metadata :{
              firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid
           }
          },
          public: false
        });
      await response.data.pipe(writeStream)
          .on('finish', () => {
              console.log('Successfully uploaded image');
              res.status(200).send();
          })
          .on('error', () => {
              console.log('Error uploading image');
              res.status(500).send();
          })
    }).catch(() => {
        console.log('Error fetching image');
        res.status(500).send();
    });
});
```

---

For more information, you may check out [Use file metadata with Cloud Storage on Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata).

Comment: Hey, thanks. I really appreciate the reply. 

I was able to change the access settings in the bucket in google cloud console (not firebase console) to be able to view the images.

The thing that confuses me is that even without setting to public, the images aren't viewable in the firebase storage console. 

Thanks for the coded example. I'm going to go through that and see if I can get the issue resolved. Thanks again. :)